# User shown as a member of deleted group

Tags: ubuntu, user, user-groups

In my ubuntu distro,

```
members user1
```

returns

```
group1: group2
```

Now, i gave

```
delgroup group1
```

& it is done successfully...
second time gave command,

```
members user1
```

returns

```
group1: group2
```

why does members command list deleted groups?

Comment: Well, by issuing `members user1` you're asking for members of _group_ `user1`, so I would suspect that `group1` and `group2` are usernames as well as group names.
What does `members group1` and `members group2` say?

Comment: i have completely messed up somewhere.... thanks, Enbyted.....